# Is there any difference in meaning with the use of the definite article?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

According to
http://amj.amegroups.com/article/view/4743/html

In the sentence,
"This study was designed to imagine the impact of the antioxidant metallothoinein (MT) on '**the**' lipopolyssacharide (LPS)-induced cardiac contractile and intracellular Ca2+ dysfunction."
the study is referring to precisely the impact of MT on specifically the LPS induced ... dysfunction.

The author of the linked article says,
using the zero-article instead of the definite article before 'lipopolysaccharide', the meaning of the sentence becomes that this paper will be looking at how LPS-induced dysfunction will impact MT. So cant use the zero article.

Would you explain me why the definite article is required in the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is not correct. Word order is what defines which thing is impacting which, and it's clear from the quoted sentence that the study is how MT impacts LPS-induced dysfunction.

The definite article is not required here.

It may not even be preferable here, because the study is presumably on all LPS-induced dysfunction, not a specific instance of LPS-induced dysfunction. Compare a simpler, but similar sentence like: "I am studying the impact of cholesterol on heart disease."